# Occurence of warning (order.by not unique) in zoo constructor

Tags: r, zoo

I was trying to create `zoo` objects from `data.frame` objects then this is what I got. I don't know what's wrong. This is the code that our professor gave. Any helping comments out there.

```
pnb.z<- zoo(x=pnb.df$PNB, order.by=dates.pnb)
```

**Warning message:**

> In zoo(x = pnb.df$PNB, order.by = dates.pnb) :   some methods for
>   “zoo” objects do not work if the index entries in ‘order.by’ are not
>   unique

Comment: You could check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17447680/r-zoo-index-entries-in-order-by-are-not-unique

Comment: Pretty informative warning,  make `dates.pnb` unique.