# Time Series date format issue in R

Tags: r, import, time-series, zoo, date-formatting

I am using the [dowjones][1] dataset but I think maybe my date format is incorrect because when I run the zoo function to make the data time series I get the warning:

> some methods for “zoo” objects do not work if the index entries in
>   ‘order.by’ are not unique

My code:

```
dow = read.table('dow_jones_index.data', header=T, sep=',')
dowts = zoo(dow$close, as.Date(as.character(dow$date), format = "%m/%d/%Y"))
```

The dates look like this: 5/6/2011

Does my error have to do with using an incorrect date format? Or something else?

Thank you.

EDIT:

```
hist(dowts, xlab='close change rate', prob=TRUE, main='Histogram',ylim=c(0,.07))
```

> Error in hist.default(dowts, xlab = "close change rate", prob = TRUE, 
>   :    character(0) 
>   In addition: Warning messages: 1: In zoo(rval[i],
>   index(x)[i]) :   some methods for “zoo” objects do not work if the
>   index entries in ‘order.by’ are not unique 2: In
>   pretty.default(range(x), n = breaks, min.n = 1) :   NAs introduced by
>   coercion   [1]:
>   https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Dow+Jones+Index

Comment: what is `zoo` method?

Comment: "Package ”zoo” provides methods for dealing with totally ordered indexed observations.In other words it allows creating and manipulating time series. However the main objective of this package is handling ”Irregular Time Series” where the base package of R doesn’t allow in handling irregularly spaced observations. Therefore key feature
is that the independence of particular index/date/time. Not only that this ”zoo” package is consistent with ”ts” and ”base” R."

Comment: I didn't want to provide my own definition since I'm new to using it, as well as dealing with time series data. Reference: http://people.stat.sfu.ca/~dac5/CompStat/CompStat2013/R_library_Student_Projects_files/Pulindu_zoo_code_report.pdf

Comment: This is not an error... It's a warning !!

Comment: For your reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17447680/r-zoo-index-entries-in-order-by-are-not-unique

Comment: Yes, but I cannot do anything after this. I have run this code on another dataset and I didn't have that warning and I was able to continue with  the code above in the edit section

Comment: Yea I saw that post but when I checked for duplicates it shows 0.

Comment: Since you ask: "Does my error have to do with using an incorrect date format?" and say your date format is "5/6/2011" which is both ambiguous and not standard, I suspect the answer is a definite yes. Dates should not look like that if they are correctly read by `zoo`. Look at dowts. If they are not in YYYY-MM-DD format then go back and convert to a real R Date vector before reading into a zoo-object.

Comment: This is answered in a comment to:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35113719/testing-skewness-in-time-series-data-using-r-but-getting-error-ncolx-1-is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem as the warning message indicates is that your date values are not unique. This is because your data is in long format with multiple stocks. A timeseries has to be in a matrix like structure with each column representing a stock and each row a point in time. With `dcast` from the package `reshape2` this straigthforward:

```
library(zoo)
library(reshape2)

dow <-  read.table('dow_jones_index.data', header=T, sep=',', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# delete $ symbol and coerce to numeric
dow$close <-  as.numeric(sub("\\$", "",dow$close))
tmp <- dcast(dow, date~stock, value.var = "close")
dowts <- as.zoo(x = tmp[,-1], order.by = as.Date(tmp$date, format = "%m/%d/%Y"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know about dcast or about the multiple stocks can't be on the same date unless they are separated into columns thing. I do have one question. Why did you remove the date in as.zoo(tmp[.-1] but then you added the date again? Why not just format the first column date in tmp?

Comment: Also a side note. I am getting another error when I test skewness that I posted here ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35113719/testing-skewness-in-time-series-data-using-r-but-getting-error-ncolx-1-is) do you by any chance know why I am getting that error? Thanks.

Comment: I don't add the date again, but provide it as an index to order.by. You could keep the date column in x as well but I don't see the point in keeping  it when you already have the data in the time-index.