# Testing Skewness in Time Series data using R but getting "Error: NCOL(x) == 1 is not TRUE"

Tags: r, statistics, time-series, skew

I am using the [Dow Jones Dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Dow+Jones+Index)
and I am trying to test skewness. So far this is the code:

```
library(tseries)
library(zoo)
library(reshape2)
library(fBasics)

dow = read.table('dow_jones_index.data', header=T, sep=',')
# create time series
dow <-  read.table('dow_jones_index.data', header=T, sep=',', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# delete $ symbol and coerce to numeric
dow$close <-  as.numeric(sub("\\$", "",dow$close))
tmp <- dcast(dow, date~stock, value.var = "close")
#tmp[,-1] means it's removing the first column (date) of tmp
dowts <- as.zoo(tmp[,-1], as.Date(tmp$date, format = "%m/%d/%Y"))

#compute simple returns ret = (p_t-p_(t-1))/p_(t-1) 
dowgrowth = (dowts-lag(dowts, k=-1))/lag(dowts, k=-1) 

#Skewness test 
skew_test = skewness(dowgrowth)/sqrt(6/length(dowgrowth))
```

Everything runs fine except the skew_test line which gives me an error of:

> Error: NCOL(x) == 1 is not TRUE

Not sure where to go from here. Thanks.

Comment: There is no `skewness` function in any of the packages listed.  If you are using the `skewness` function in the timeDate package then it accepts vectors and the code above is giving it a 2dimensional zoo object.  Also, note that `dowts` and `dowgrowth` could be computed like this: `dowts <- read.zoo(dow[c("stock", "date", "close")], 
   index = "date", split = "stock", format = "%m/%d/%Y");
dowgrowth <- diff(dowts, arithmetic = FALSE) - 1`

Comment: WOW thank you so much! I changed the code to 'skew_test=apply(dowgrowth, 2, function(x) skewness(x)/sqrt(6/length(x)))'

Comment: couldn't edit the above but I figured out how to mark the code as a piece of code...   `skew_test=apply(dowgrowth, 2, function(x) skewness(x)/sqrt(6/length(x)))` Also thank you for showing me the other way of computing dowts and dowgrowth. I'm confused about dowgrowth a bit, how come there is a lag parameter but you never use it? I tried this...  `dowgrowth_alt2<- diff(dowts, arithmetic = FALSE, lag=1)  ####THIS DOES NOT WORK` but the answer is different and therefore wrong. Why do you subtract the whole thing instead of using the parameter? I tried to read what diff is but I don't understand

Comment: I would like to give you best answer but there is no way to mark it in the comments. :/